# Aligning a textview after a textview it was aligned to visibility is gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image: This is my screen]

When the coupon which is the small icon is gone, this part in the layout

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    tools:visibility="gone"/>
```

[image: Should align like in the green box]

The green box I have drawn should be where the description should be aligned.
I have tried using the barrier but could get that to work

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCartItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/highlineView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_6dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/yellowHighlineColor"
            />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13"/>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_semi"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
            tools:text="12" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
            android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12sp"
            android:maxLength="3"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
            tools:text="Mon" />

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_44dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_semi"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="This is the title" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#FF3D1C"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
            tools:text="This is the description" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewChevron"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/icons_chevron_right" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: You can try adding two guidelines, where it has to be aligned, then change to each of the  guidelines according to visibility of that token icon

Comment: Did you consider deleting the `ImageView` and adding a `drawableLeft` to the `TextView`? It also supports a `drawablePadding`.

Comment: check my edited answer, with blank view wrapped in separate layout will help you to avoid margin problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `ConstraintLayout` feature and set `app:layout_goneMarginStart="12dp"` (the Start Margin of `ImageView`) for Material text view.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. The easiest and quickest solution.

Answer (score 3):

> **Edit**:
> Here is new idea to have blank view of size 4dp wrapped in ConstraintLayout.

The only catch is you need to do visibility on layout which contains Imageview & View (EmptyView).

[image]

Your XML should look like:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#FF3D1C"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:text="This is the description" />
```

Below is the sample result if you do visibility = gone.

[image]

> Alternatively, you should use same bottom textview and use drawableStart, which allows drawablePadding option.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make two changes one remove start margin and second change start Constraint.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: I did try that. However, it won't work as the `textViewDescription` has a `android:layout_marginStart="4dp"` As there needs to be a gap between the imageViewCoupon and the textViewDescription. So when the  imageViewCoupon is gone the 4dp margin will be miss aligned

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:elevation="@dimen/margin_0dp"
app:cardElevation="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutCartItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/highlineView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/yellowHighlineColor"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/headerGL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.27" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_semi"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
        tools:text="12" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
        android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12sp"
        android:maxLength="3"
        app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
        tools:text="Mon" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_44dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"          
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
        app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_semi"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="This is the title" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/headerGL"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#FF3D1C"
        app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
        tools:text="This is the description" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewChevron"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icons_chevron_right" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd add a barrier to the end of the `imageView` avatar, and transfer the start `12dp` margin of the `imageViewCoupon` & `textViewTitle` to that barrier using `app:barrierMargin` attribute:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierMargin="@dimen/margin_12dp"
    app:barrierDirection="right"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView" />
```

Then constraint the start of the `imageViewCoupon` & `textViewTitle` to that barrier:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    tools:visibility="visible" />

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="This is the title"
    android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Now when the `imageViewCoupon` is gone, the `textViewDescription` will be constrained to the barrier.

Upon those modifications, the entire layout would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutCartItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/highlineView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_6dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/yellowHighlineColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.13" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-6dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
            android:maxLength="2"
            android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_semi"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="12" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
            android:maxLength="3"
            android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateHorizontal"
            tools:text="Mon" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
            android:id="@+id/barrier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:barrierMargin="@dimen/margin_12dp"
            app:barrierDirection="right"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="imageView" />
        
        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_44dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_44dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideLineDisplayDateVertical"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/blackSectionTitle"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_semi"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="This is the title" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/barrier"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#FF3D1C"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
            tools:text="This is the description" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewChevron"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/icons_chevron_right"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

*try this*

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/li_bi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/av"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:background="@color/green"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_b"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/av"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/dim_10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MoN"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/date_b"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/domepro"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
            android:padding="@dimen/dim_10dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is the title"
                android:paddingVertical="2dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_pdf"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:padding="2dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="This is the decription"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingVertical="2dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im_ar"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrowright"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

***You answered your own question by drawing the box in green which is what you need to make...***

You just put all what you have inside box in 1 view and make inner view alignments with this box which will fix your problem.

Means your Title, image, description will go in one view and Title, image, description will align with this view...

Also

Just update to the below.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_coupon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    tools:visibility="visible"/>

<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/order_label_lines_pace_extra"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textColor="#FF3D1C"
    app:fontFamily="@font/ibmp_lexsansthai_regular"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewCoupon"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/imageViewChevron"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
    tools:text="This is the description" />
```

I shift `layout_marginStart` from `textViewDescription` to `layout_marginEnd` in `imageViewCoupon`

Using this when image is hidden, automatically description will come to start of the view...